# regExpression.test

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var regExpression = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)$/; //line 2
//// var regExpression = "/" + "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)$" + "/"; //line 3
alert (regExpression.test("11aa"));
```

The  above code is working fine.
But if we replace line 2 by line 3 then it is not working 
why?
i am in a situation like I want to create the var only by appending(the expression come dynamically) so what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Line 3 sets `regExpression` to a string. Strings does not have a `test` method. You need to turn the string into a RegExp.

```
var regExpression = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)$");
```

Omit the slashes, as they are not part of the regexp itself.

Comment: That's because the backslashes should have been doubled, as explained by @Nick Craver in his answer to your followup question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3864657/20938

Answer (score 0):

If you like to create a RegExp dynamically, use [new RegExp()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp).
This allows you to build the expression with string-functions