# new RegExp. test

Tags: javascript, regex

I have posted a problem in the above link - [regExpression.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861970/regexpression-test).

Based on that I have done like bellow that also produces an error.

```
var regExpression=new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)$");
alert (regExpression.test("11aa"));
```

Comment: I don't think asking another similar question is the way to go here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regExpression.test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861970/regexpression-test)

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your `\` since you're declaring it with a string, like this:

```
var regExpression=new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)$"); 
                                           ^  ^ add these
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/juk48/).

Comment: i will have to replace all \ by \\ is there any such charecter(even it is  not in this regex) to be replaced?

Comment: it would be better to just remove the existing backslashes.

Comment: @Nick: would it? jsfiddle doesn't

Comment: @SilentGhost - Sure it does, check your console: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/juk48/1/ ...notice how you're not getting an alert, true *or* false?

Comment: @NIck: well that has nothing to do with backslashes, it's just that `-` should be placed last (error is due to the bad range, I think). You see, still functions as normal.

Comment: @SilentGhost - "just remove the existing backslashes" was your comment...that's what I was responding to, *that* would result in a script error.  Yes changing the order as @Gumbo suggests works just fine, but that wasn't your comment.

Comment: @Nick: it's the most obvious thing to do, so the script doesn't throw an error ;)

Comment: @SilentGhost - You're missing the point entirely, you need to remove the backslashes *and* make other changes.

Comment: +1. To answer @user444569's question in the first comment: Yes, **if** there are backslashes in the regex, they must themselves be escaped with backslashes if the regex is written in the form of a string literal (that is, as `new RegExp("...")` or `new RegExp('...')` instead of as `/.../`).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [literal RegExp syntax `/…/`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var regExpression = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)$/;
```

By the way: The `.` does not need to be escaped in character classes anyway. And if you put the range operator at the begin or the end of the character class or immediately after a character range, it doesn’t need to be escaped either:

```
var regExpression = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$/;
```